# How (at an implementation level) does Java RMI load+define classes?

Tags: java, serialization, classloader, rmi

When RMI (the `sun.rmi` implementation in Sun VMs) is de-serializing an object, as part of either the parameters or return value of a remote call, it needs to go from the class's name (a string in the serialized data) to a `Class` object. How does RMI decide which `ClassLoader` to use to define the class?

Answer (score 2):

By default Java deserialisation searches down the stack for the first non-system class and uses its class loader (i.e. the first non-null class loader). RMI adds annotations the serial stream to give the location (URL) where the classes should be downloaded from. By default, RMI class loaders uses that location to find additional classes. There is a system property to switch that behaviour off (not a bad idea).

Comment: So, basically, assuming no remote codebases are specified, a return value gets loaded by the ClassLoader that loaded the Class that made the call into the stub? (Or the ClassLoader that defined particular Proxy class that the stub is an instanceof?) What about on the server? Until UnicastServerRef makes the actual upcall into the exported object, at which point parameters have all been deserialized, all the stack frames should be system classes, since it's on one of RMI's dispatch threads. Right?

Comment: @jon I believe you get either the class loader of the server object or the context it was exported in (usually the same).

Comment: None of that is 'by default'. You have to set the java.rmi.server.codebase property at the JVM that exports the remote object to get the whole process started. I don't know what the 'system class' you refer to is. RMI doesn't use 'default Java serialization', it adds a layer of its own that overrides resolveClass().

Comment: @EJP Tom's answer is correct. He describes standard Java deserialization (i.e. ObjectInputStream) accurately; by "system class", he means a class loaded by the null ClassLoader. The default for RMI deserialization (i.e. MarshalInputStream) is to respect any annotation in the stream (as long as a SecurityManager is installed) and otherwise to fall back to default ObjectInputStream behavior (calling side) or something slightly more complicated (called side.) I'll write up something more detailed later.

Comment: @jon It is certainly not correct as regards the codebase feature. I don't know what the 'system class to switch off that behaviour' might me.

Comment: @EJP I assume you're referring to your earlier comment, "you have to set the java.rmi.server.codebase property at the JVM that exports the remote object"? This question is only about deserialization. If there are annotations, MarshalInputStream respects them; under what circumstances a MarshalOutputStream includes them is off-topic.I will grant you that 'system class to switch off that behaviour' is incorrect; it's a system property.

Comment: @Jon 'By default, RMI class loaders uses that location' cannot be true if 'by default', 'that location' isn't even there.